# Select group that every member of that team dont have specific value in column

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE Dzialania
(id_harcerza int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
id_sprawnosci text NOT NULL);
```

```
id_harcerza | id_sprawnosci
-----------------------------
1           | S1
1           | S2
2           | S6
2           | S4
3           | S6
4           | S3
```

```
CREATE TABLE Harcerze
(id_harcerza int NOT NULL,
Druzyna text NOT NULL);
```

```
id_harcerza | druzyna
-----------------------------
1           | Team1
2           | Team2
3           | Team2
4           | Team1
5           | Team3
```

Hi guys, im so tired so i need your help with some SQL.

So i have two tables, "Harcerze" and "Dzialania".
I need to select only one "Druzyna" that every member of that group dont have S6 value in "Id_sprawnosci" column in "Dzialania" table

On that example data i used above. It should return Team1 because its the only group that dont have any member with S6 value.

Comment: Team3 doesn't have a S6 entry either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  h.druzyna
FROM
  Harcerze    AS h
INNER JOIN
  Dzialania   AS d
    ON d.id_harcerza = h.id_harcerza
GROUP BY
  h.druzyna
HAVING
  COUNT(CASE WHEN d.id_sprawnosci = 'S6' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: @kamilpinas Please upvote and/or accept any and all answers that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `left join` and `group by` with a `having` clause:

```
select d.druzyna
from Dzialania d left join
     Harcerze h
     on h.id_harcerza = d.id_harcerza and
        h.id_sprawnosci = 6
group by d.druzyna
having count(h.id_harcerza) = 0;
```

Comment: That would also return Team3 but the OP apparently only wants Team1